# SSAS/MDX - Sum and Group Results - Date Comparison

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I am working on a MDX Dataset from a TFS2010 Cube (I Have also posted on the Team Foundation Server - Reporting & Warehouse forum).

I am looking to produce the trend of aged defects over the last several months.  I have code producing the data that I need, for I am unable to get it to count in the way I need for the SSRS line graph.  Here is the code:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AgedGroupTotal] AS ([Measures].[Work Item Count])
MEMBER [Measures].[AgedGroup30] AS IIF(DATEDIFF("d", [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].CurrentMember.Name, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name) <= 30, [Measures].[Work Item Count], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[AgedGroup3060] AS IIF(DATEDIFF("d", [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].CurrentMember.Name, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name) > 30 AND DATEDIFF("d", [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].CurrentMember.Name, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name) <= 60, [Measures].[Work Item Count], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[AgedGroup6090] AS IIF(DATEDIFF("d", [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].CurrentMember.Name, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name) > 60 AND DATEDIFF("d", [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].CurrentMember.Name, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name) <= 90, [Measures].[Work Item Count], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[AgedGroup90] AS  IIF(DATEDIFF("d", [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].CurrentMember.Name, [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name) > 90, [Measures].[Work Item Count], null)
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[AgedGroup30], [Measures].[AgedGroup90], [Measures].[AgedGroup6090], [Measures].[AgedGroup3060], [Measures].[AgedGroupTotal] }
ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Month].[Month].ALLMEMBERS *
[Date].[Week].[Week].ALLMEMBERS *
[Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS *
[Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].[System_CreatedDate].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( [Date].[Date].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00] : [Date].[Date].&[2013-03-31T00:00:00] )
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Work Item].[System_State].&[Active] } )
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug] } )
ON COLUMNS FROM [Work Item])))
WHERE ([Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug], [Work Item].[System_State].&[Active])
```

Here is the result:
PIC:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/258636

Month   Week    Date    Created Date    AgedGroup30 AgedGroup90 AgedGroup6090   AgedGroup3060   AgedGroupTotal
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    3/15/2012   (null)  2   (null)  (null)  2
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    3/21/2012   (null)  3   (null)  (null)  3
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    3/29/2012   (null)  1   (null)  (null)  1
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    3/30/2012   (null)  0   (null)  (null)  0
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    4/3/2012    (null)  1   (null)  (null)  1
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    4/5/2012    (null)  5   (null)  (null)  5
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    4/6/2012    (null)  10  (null)  (null)  10
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    4/12/2012   (null)  0   (null)  (null)  0
January, 2013   Week ending January 05  1/1/2013    4/14/2012   (null)  2   (null)  (null)  2

The problem is the [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].[System_CreatedDate].ALLMEMBERS needing to be included in the result.  Without this member being included, the DATEDIFF formula's for the age groups do not calculate and give an #Error.  If I output this data into an SSRS table with a SUM on the AgedGroups, and exclude the created date, I get the data set I need:

PIC:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/258639

Month   Week    Date    Aged Group30    Aged Group3060  Aged Group6090  Aged Group90    AgedGroupTotal
February, 2013  Week ending February 02 2/1/2013    20  1   2   2   25
    2/2/2013    20  1   2   2   25
    Week ending February 09 2/3/2013    20  1   2   2   25
    2/4/2013    28  0   3   2   33
    2/5/2013    37  0   3   2   42
    2/6/2013    50  1   3   1   55
    2/7/2013    60  1   7   3   71
    2/8/2013    58  2   7   3   70
    2/9/2013    58  2   7   3   70

The issue is that I need this summed result in my MDX dataset.  However, I can not exclude the Created date, which creates the issue.  I am new to MDX, but in SQL this operation would be simple with using a TEMP table and sum/group by.  However, I know MDX does not work this way.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get this dataset in MDX?

Thank you for any help,

Evgapro